# You have an error in your SQL syntax... getting error when creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, xampp

I have wrote trigger for my DB.

```
CREATE TRIGGER executor_type_check BEFORE INSERT ON executors 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.points <> 100
    SET NEW.points = 0; 
  END IF; 
END
```

I get the following error upon importing sql file

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.points = 0' at line 5
```

My .sql file has the following structure:

1. DataBase creation
2. start transaction
3. creation of tables
4. creation of trigger
5. commit

Without trigger no error is shown.

Comment: Missing `then`?

Comment: Missing '; ' after END

Comment: Try putting `DELIMITER $$` or something similar before the trigger definition.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Comments` below your Question.

You are missing `THEN` after the `IF` statement. And also need to Add `DELIMITER`.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER executor_type_check BEFORE INSERT ON executors 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.points <> 100
  THEN
    SET NEW.points = 0; 
  END IF; 
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thank you, using your code i don't get the error, but strangely when i try to insert into table, trigger doesn't seem to fire. E.g. when I input 99 (which is different to 100) it still inserts 99, instead of 0.